# Where are legacy references to the database tables of django models are hidden?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am restructuring the postgresql database: renaming tables, changing foreign keys and linking the new and modified tables to the django models. But the old reference to the table `historical_models_liveanalogvalue` and an old attribute `ts` name appears in one of the models (maybe in all of them, but the code exits with an error). Django native migrations are out of the question due to some internal reasons even though it could have prevented this problem.

I had to do `inspectdb`, based on that, fix the `models.py` and perform migrations with `--fake-initial` to keep the project running.

Where else could the old reference be found and deleted?

I searched for all the appearances of the string with the old table name but could not find anything. I tried to put the table name in double quotes, but also did not work.
The new model in the `models.py` is the following:

```
@architect.install('partition', type='range', subtype='date', 
constraint='day',column='source_timestamp')
class LiveData(models.Model):
    """The base class for live models."""

    # Timestamp when the sample was created.
    source_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        """Meta specification."""
        managed = False
        db_table = 'livedata'
```

The new `0001_initial.py`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LiveData',
            fields=[('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, 
            primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('source_timestamp',  models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)),
        ],

        options={
            'managed': False,
            'db_table': 'livedata',
        }]
```

The legacy model is following:

```
@architect.install('partition', type='range', subtype='date', 
constraint='day',
               column='ts')
class LiveAnalogValue(models.Model):
"""Live analogue values."""
    ts = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, blank=False, 
    null=False)
```

The application name is:

```
historical_models
```

And the error is produced at the call:

```
model.save():

One by one insertion failed for: LiveData object: invalid type name         "historical_models_liveanalogvalue."ts"%TYPE"
LINE 3:  match historical_models_liveanalogvalue....
                              ^
QUERY:  
            DECLARE
                match historical_models_liveanalogvalue."ts"%TYPE;
                tablename VARCHAR;
                checks TEXT;

            BEGIN
                IF NEW."ts" IS NULL THEN
                    tablename :=         'historical_models_liveanalogvalue_null';
                    checks := '"ts" IS NULL';
                ELSE
                    match := DATE_TRUNC('day', NEW."ts");
                    tablename :=     'historical_models_liveanalogvalue_' || TO_CHAR(NEW."ts", '"y"YYYY"d"DDD');
                    checks := '"ts" >= ''' || match || ''' AND "ts"     < ''' || (match + INTERVAL '1 day') || '''';
                END IF;

                IF NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE     table_name=tablename)
                THEN
                    BEGIN
                        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || tablename || ' (
                            CHECK (' || checks || '),
                            LIKE "historical_models_liveanalogvalue"            
 INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING
 CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES
                        ) INHERITS ("historical_models_liveanalogvalue");';
                    EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
                        -- pass
                    END;
                END IF;

                EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES (($1).*);' USING NEW;
                RETURN NEW;
            END;

CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function     
"historical_models_liveanalogvalue_insert_child" near line 3
```

If I am not mistaken this sql query is automatically generated during the call to `model.save()`

UPDATE: found this query in the folder `postgres/database/base/` but still cannot figure out how it appered there.

Comment: This is not something that is done by Django. Perhaps whatever those `architect` decorators are is doing it.

Comment: In the end, it was a trigger in the database itself that needed to be fixed as well. Solved